# Not able to execute Jmeter using java code

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to run Jmeter through my code but the result shows error.
error :Non HTTP response code: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,Non HTTP response message: URI can't be null.,threadGroup

```
    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/Users/apple/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.1");
    //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/Users/apple/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    // JMeter Test Plan, basic all u JOrphan HashTree
    HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();


    // HTTP Sampler
    HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();

    httpSampler.setDomain("http://url");
    httpSampler.setPort(8080);
    httpSampler.setPath("/");
    httpSampler.setMethod("GET");
    HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();
    headerManager.add(new Header("Content-type", "application/json"));
    headerManager.add(new Header("Authorization", "Basic *****"));
  //  headerManager.add(new Header("Postman-Token", "***"));

    httpSampler.setHeaderManager(headerManager);

    // Loop Controller
    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    loopController.setContinueForever(true);
    loopController.setLoops(1);
    loopController.setFirst(true);
```

//        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
//        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
       loopController.initialize();
        loopController.setEnabled(true);

```
    // Thread Group
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setName("threadGroup");
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
    threadGroup.setScheduler(true);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(0);
    threadGroup.setDuration(60);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
```

//        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
  //      threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setEnabled(true);

```
    ///Report
    Summariser summer = null;
    String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
    if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
        summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
    }


    String logFile = "/Users/apple/result.jtl";
    ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
    logger.setFilename(logFile);

    // code below is use to add authorization

    HashTree requestHashTree = new HashTree();
    requestHashTree.add(httpSampler, headerManager);
    // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements

    // Test Plan
    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
    //
    testPlanTree.add(httpSampler, headerManager);

    // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
    testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
    HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
    threadGroupHashTree.add(requestHashTree);


    // code above is use to add authorization
    //
    // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
    testPlanTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
    testPlanTree.add("loopController", loopController);
    testPlanTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
    testPlanTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);
    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);


    // Run Test Plan
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();
```